# Converting lambda (cpp) to function pointer (for c)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, lambda, runtime

I am trying to implement a parallel runtime using argobots api.

In the main.cpp I am using a lambda function which is argument to the "kernel" function in lib.cpp. I need to convert the lambda received in lib.hpp to a function pointer and call "lib_kernel" in lib.c. I have read many answers and came to know that converting lambdas (capture by reference) to function pointer is not possible. Is there any alternative?. I also don't have any idea how deal with the template parameter T in the "kernel" function. Please help.

// main.cpp

```
#include "lib.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int result;
    lib::kernel([&]() {
        result = fib(10); 
    }); 
    cout << "Fib(10) = " << result << "\n";
    // fib is parallel implementation of fibonacci
    // similar to passing function pointers to threads
}
```

// lib.hpp

```
namespace lib {

    void kernel(T &&lambda) {
        // T is template argument
        // Need to convert lambda to function pointer
        // ie. lib_kernel(fptr, args)
        // Here fptr and args are received from lambda
        // ie. fptr will be fib function 
        // args is value 10.
    }
}
```

// lib.c

```
typedef void (*fork_t)(void* args);

void lib_kernel(fork_t fptr, void* args) {
    fptr(args);
}
```

Comment: Is `args` something that you pass and get back from callback?

Comment: args is a structure which contains an int n for fibonacci and an int variable storing return value.
ie main func in c
fib_arg_t arg = {10, 0};
lib_kernel(fib, &arg);
printf("fib(10) = %d\n", arg.ret);

Comment: `// T is a template` ? Do you mean `kernel` is a function template and `T` is its template argument?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: Yes  T is a template argument

Comment: As for your problem, one possible workaround is to pass a pointer to an actual function.

Comment: The question might not be a duplicate, but it looks like this answer can be applied to your situation: [A: call a C++ method from a C callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854385) -- don't ignore the second parameter to `lib_kernel`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please check if updated code does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a lambda to a function pointer with `+`, i.e.:

```
typedef void (*func)(void* args);

void kernel(func fn, void* args){ 
    fn(args);
}

void CallKernelWithLambda() {
    func f = +[](void*) { };
    kernel(f, nullptr);
}
```

However, lambdas that capture cannot be converted to a function pointer -- the following fails to compile:

```
typedef void (*func)(void* args);

void kernel(func fn, void* args){ 
    fn(args);
}

void CallKernelWithLambda() {
    int value = 0;
    func f = +[&](void*) { ++value; };
    kernel(f, nullptr);
}
```

You need to put the value that you want to capture in static storage or global scope, e.g.:

```
typedef void (*func)(void* args);

void kernel(func fn, void* args){ 
    fn(args);
}

int value = 0;
void CallKernelWithLambda() {
    func f = +[](void*) { ++value; };
    kernel(f, nullptr);
}
```

Putting the call to `kernel` inside of a templated function doesn't make any difference, i.e.:

```
typedef void (*func)(void* args);

void kernel(func fn, void* args){ 
    fn(args);
}

template <typename T>
void CallKernelWithTemplateArgumentLambda(T&& lambda) {
    kernel(+lambda, nullptr);
}
int value = 0;
void CallKernelWithLambda() {
    CallKernelWithTemplateArgumentLambda([](void*) { ++value; });
}
```

behaves the same way as the previous snippet.

Comment: Singletons are bad. Since the library function accepts a `void *`, you should pass your parameters there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, but my impression from the question is that OP doesn't control the kernel function, so if they want to do something like "track the number of times the lambda is invoked," it can't be done without introducing some global state.

Comment: The `void *` parameter makes it possible. See my answer...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm assuming this call to the kernel function is buried deep inside of a library that OP doesn't control, since otherwise the desire to put mutable state in the lambda makes less sense.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the address of the capturing lambda into the second parameter (`void *`). Make a second (non-capturing) lambda to call it:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(void (*func)(void *), void *arg)
{
    func(arg);
}

int main()
{
    int var = 42;
    auto lambda = [&]{std::cout << var << '\n';};
    foo([](void *f){(*(decltype(lambda) *)f)();}, &lambda);
}
```