# Swift: Using C++ library from Swift results to Linkage error, BUT WHY?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make a c++ library work under Swift. I'm a noob in both, so I could be doing something completely stupid but do appreciate all the feedback. I have the following setup:

AnswerToEverything.cpp:

```
#include "AnswerToEverything.h"
#include <iostream>

class Everything{

    int answerToEverything()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};
```

AnswerToEverything.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int answerToEverything();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer-Bridging-Header.h:

```
 #include "AnswerToEverything.h"
```

GameScene.swift:

```
...
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        println("C++ call: \(answerToEverything())")
}
...
```

The Result is:

[image]

So what am I missing? All help Appreciated!

Comment: In the header you declare a global 'extern C' function answerToEverything, in the source you have define a class with a member function answerToEverything. Those are two different and completely unrelated functions. Which of them do you actually need/want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a `"C"` function which creates your `C++` object and calls its method as is plotted out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815274/calling-c-class-method-from-c). All the solutions look somewhat ugly, but you will have to expect that if you mix the two. Once you have a statically linkable `C`-function it will be found by the linker. Currently it is just telling you that you do not have one. As @stijn pointed out a `C++` member method is nothing of that kind.

Comment: Thanks! I took out the class and started to write a new c++ function into "AnswerToEverything.cpp". On the first include I run into trouble: <br><br> #include <vector> results into: 'vector' file not found. Is there something that I have to do for the compiler settings etc?

Comment: @user3673836: You won't be able to be very clear in a comment as you can only inline your code. You should edit your question (by adding an **Update:** tag and your new code/problem) or create a new, more specific question.