# error C2040: 'MyClass' : 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'MyClass'

Tags: c++

I wrote it C_Wrapper of a DLL (C ++).
Header File

```
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif
typedef void* MyClass;
DLLIMPORT MyClass* createWrapper(double a, double b);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Source File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "C_DllWrapper.h"

DLLIMPORT MyClass* createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
   return new MyClass(a,b); 
}
```

I get the following error message:
error C2040: 'MyClass' : 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'MyClass'

---

I've changed my C_Wrapper:

Header Files:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif

extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b);
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void* instance);
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) double Add(void* instance, double a, double b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif
```

Source Files:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "C_DllWrapper.h"

extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
  return new MyClass(a,b); 
}

 extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void *instance)
{
  delete static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
}
 extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a, double b)
{
 MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
 return myClass->Add(a, b);
}
```

Is that right?

---

what is better?:

```
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
  return new MyClass(a,b); 
}

 extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void *instance)
 {
    delete static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
 }
  extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a, double b)
  {
     MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
     return myClass->Add(a, b);
   }
```

or That:

```
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
  return new MyClass(a,b); 
}

extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void *instance)
{
  delete static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
}
extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a, double b)
{
 MyClass *myClass = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
  return myClass->Add(a, b);
}
```

---

This code can I run with Visual Studio and LabVIEW in debug mode.
There is no error occurred.

Now I understand question:
The first I have actually can create the object MyClass only and I do where 
call the createWrapper function (double a, double b) (thus the object created).
Until here everything is ok.
If I call, for example, this function :

```
  extern "C"__declspec (dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a,   double b)
  {
     MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
     return myClass->Add(a, b);
  }
```

how can I tell my object (Pointer) "MyClass" make known in LabVIEW  for this function?

or rather how can I object to the pointer "void * instance" referenced.
For example, if I write a test program (C ++), I will proceed as follows:

```
 int main ()
{
  void * testref;
  testref = create (1.2);
  Add (testref, 5.6);
  ......
}
```

This is in c ++ but what is in Labview.
How can I get this object "void * testref" for all remaining functions use.

Sorry for my english

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a single file? Also, where is the error exactly?

Comment: Well you *did* make a type-alias of `MyClass` as `void *`, what do you think happens when you do e.g. `new MyClass(...)`?

Comment: Also note that `createWrapper` in your code is declared to return a pointer to a pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Your `typedef` is wrecking havoc with your code. You don't need it. The typedef is causing the compiler to get confused when it sees `new MyClass` as you've redefined `MyClass` as `void*`.

1. Remove the `typedef void* MyClass` line.
2. Change your `createWrapper` function's signature to `void* createWrapper`
3. Add `extern "C"` to the `createWrapper` function definition, not just its declaration.

If you're developing a C API that is a flat representation of an object's methods, consider adopting an OOP-esque naming convention ("`Noun_Verb`" names instead of using `VerbNoun` names) as they will be more organised when examining a listing of all functions in your code.

Also, do not forget to define a function that `delete`s or otherwise releases your object instance:

```
extern "C" void* MyClass_create() {
    return new MyClass();
}

extern "C" void  MyClass_destroy(void* instance) {
    delete static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
}
```

I recommend reading this QA for more information and plenty of helpful examples: [How to call a C++ method from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815274/how-to-call-a-c-method-from-c)

I also suspect you're using `DLLIMPORT` incorrectly, as I believe you're actually *exporting* these functions. I feel it's better to use `__declspec` directly instead of using macros. The syntax is `__declspec(dllexport)`, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx