# Using C++ classes in C: How to properly write some sort of "delete/dispose" function?

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, destructor, dispose

I need to use a C++ class in C code.

With such a C++ class:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    void myFunction()
    {
        cout << "Value = " << m_value;
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

I have the following wrapper:

```
typedef void CMyClass;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

CMyClass * new_MyClass();
void c_myFunction(const CMyClass * ptr);
void c_dispose( ??? ); // to delete/destruct

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// implementation below:

CMyClass * new_CMyClass() 
{
    MyClass * ptr = new MyClass();
    return (CMyClass*)ptr;
}

void c_myFunction(const CMyClass * ptr) 
{
    MyClass * tmp = (MyClass*)ptr;
    tmp->myFunction();
}

void c_dispose( ??? )
{
    /* ??? */
}
```

I would like just to make sure I won't have any problems like memory leaks, zombie pointers, with my `c_dispose` function.

How to properly write the complete code for `c_dispose(???)` to delete the previously created (with `new_CMyClass()`) object instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815274/how-to-call-a-c-method-from-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to simply call the `delete` once you casted the C type to C++ class.

```
void c_dispose(CMyClass * ptr){
    MyClass * tmp = (MyClass*)ptr;  
    delete tmp;
}
```

Comment: You can set `ptr` to NULL if you like. But if you do not do that the memory will be freed anyway.

Comment: @groenhen: nulling pointers is in general a very ineffective practice. It gives a false sense of security (which is arguably worse than no sense of security at all) because nulling one pointer after freeing it does not null all its copies... which are now dangling. The only reason to null a pointer after freeing its pointee is to "recycle" it later, which requires keeping it around in the mean-time.